# Carbon to Cocoa conversion library?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

Does anyone know of a library that has a C++ Carbon API to call equivalent 64-bit Cocoa functions? I need to port a Carbon-based 32-bit C++ app to 64-bit, but am dreading having to code for Cocoa in Objective C.

Thanks!

Bill

Comment: I don't think a down-vote is fair. This isn't a bad question in itself. Seeking a direct-port shortcut might not be a good idea but there's nothing wrong with asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only available mechanism is to learn the new platform and write the application or library anew. There are *many* differences between Carbon and Cocoa. The latter, for example, follows the model/view/controller design pattern. A lot of other differences abound (for example, the drawing system is completely different). A direct mirroring between the two would be shaky at best but is just not a good idea.

In short: do yourself and your users a favor and learn the new platform. Very fortunately, Cocoa really is quite a pleasure to work with by comparison.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a business opportunity though... Have a Happy New Year!